# What does Android N (Preview) refer to under "Build target"

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using intellij idea for android development. I presume it is the same thing as android studio. I imported an existing android project into intellij idea, using the following instructions:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/importing-an-existing-android-project.html?origin=old_help

Under step 8) in the ordered list, I specified the Java SDK 1.8 and continued the import. Now when I launched intellij idea, I got the following error:

> Android SDK is not configured for module "X" or corrupted

So I opened the project structure. I went to Platform Settings > SDKs. Since I already specified the Java SDK during the import, now I need to specify the Android SDK. I clicked the + sign and specified Android SDK. Then I went to the root directory of my SDK install (android-sdk-macosx) and selected that folder.

Now I get a little popup that says:

```
Create New Android SDK
Java SDK: 1.8 
Build target: Android N (Preview)
```

I have the latest Android SDK (Android 6.0). But I also have Android SDK 4.1.2 to work on older devices. But I also use google maps so I have also Google APIs 6.0 and 4.1.2 respectively.

In other words, I have 5 options for Build target:

```
Android N (Preview)
Android 6.0
Android 4.1.2
Google APIs 6.0
Google APIS 4.1.2
```

Which one do I select?

Comment: I would recommend using an actual android studio install. You can download it [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: @AlexTownsend intellij-idea is the same code. I use intellij-idea because I use it for other platforms as well e.g. java, ruby on rails, nodejs. I do not know what Android N (Preview) refers to.

Comment: the N preview refers to the preview SDK for the next Android version (currently called N). Android 6.0 would be for Android Marshmallow (the current highest release version of Android).

Comment: @AlexTownsend Android Studio would have the exact same option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I also use google maps so I have also Google APIs 6.0 and 4.1.2 respectively

Unless you are using the long-since-deprecated Maps V1 API, you do not need those Google APIs build targets. Maps V2, the current edition of the Android integration for Google Maps, can be built using a normal build target and the appropriate Play Services SDK.

> Which one do I select?

Android 6.0, most likely. That equates to what in Android Studio would be a `compileSdkVersion` of 23.

Choosing `'N'` limits you to testing with the N Developer Preview. Since you have not mentioned this, I am assuming that this is not your objective.